# Test in deployed war

Tags: java, spring, testing, deployment

Test doesn't starts. When I try it with embedded Tomcat - everything is fine.

When I deploy test to Wildfly - I've got error: 
"Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean."

Server log and source code here:
https://github.com/cheryuriy/books/tree/master/src/main/java/server

Test is in "unit" package. Test's annotations:

```
@TestPropertySource("/application-unit.properties")
@SpringBootTest(classes = Start.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@Transactional
@DirtiesContext
public class Tests extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests
{...
```

I load test by LoadTest class:

```
@Profile("unit")
@Component
public class LoadTest {
    @PostConstruct
    public void Start()throws Exception{
            XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
            suite.setName("TmpSuite");
            XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
            test.setName("TmpTest");
            List<XmlClass> classes = new ArrayList<XmlClass>();
            classes.add(new XmlClass("server.unit.Tests"));
            test.setXmlClasses(classes);
            List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
            suites.add(suite);
            TestNG tng = new TestNG();
            tng.setXmlSuites(suites);
            tng.run();
}}
```

Test's results:

===============================================
2017-10-01 10:58:09,964 INFO [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) TmpSuite
2017-10-01 10:58:09,964 INFO [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Total tests run: 5, Failures: 0, **Skips: 5**
2017-10-01 10:58:09,964 INFO [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) **Configuration Failures: 1**, Skips: 0
2017-10-01 10:58:09,980 INFO [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) ===============================================

Thanks for help.